# How to check if value is empty in PHP [JSON]

Tags: php

I have some JSON parameters, that I want to validate if the value are empty with an IF statement. I have written an IF statement in a function to check, but the IF statement only checks for the parameter, I want to check for the values if they are empty. Please, how do I go about this.
my code

```
   //api.php

    $payment_type = $this->validateParameter('payment_type', $this->param['payment_type'], STRING, true);

$date_of_delivery = $this->validateParameter('date_of_delivery', $this->param['date_of_delivery'], STRING, true);

 $your_generated_waybill_number = $this->validateParameter('your_generated_waybill_number', $this->param['your_generated_waybill_number'], STRING, true);


   "payment_type" - is an example of parameter ||  "1" - is an example of value



     {
  "name":"create_insert_new_delivery",
  "param":{
       "payment_type":"1",
       "date_of_delivery":"", //E.g here want to check if the value is empty
       "your_generated_waybill_number":"39ei40909444567avaab",
       }
    }





  //rest.php
   public function validateParameter($fieldName, $value, $required = true){

    if($required == true && empty($value) == true){
        $this->throwError(EMPTY_PARAMETER, $fieldName . " parameter is missing"); //HERE check if the parameter is missing and fires error, but I also want to include value check
    } else if ($required == true && empty($fieldName) == true){
        $this->throwError(API_PARAM_REQUIRED, $fieldName . " value is required");
    } else {

    } //check when parameter is present but value is empty and leave if it is not required

  }
```

Comment: Did you see, your method is 3 args while you're calling it with 4 ? And did you see you assign their calls in variables while the method have no return ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may make your function a little clearer since the tests you are doing will already return true or false. There is no need to compare them to true.

```
if ($required AND empty($value)) {
        $this->throwError(EMPTY_PARAMETER, $fieldName . " parameter is missing"); //HERE check if the parameter is missing and fires error, but I also want to include value check
    } elseif ($required AND empty($fieldName)) {
        $this->throwError(API_PARAM_REQUIRED, $fieldName . " is required");
    } elseif (!empty($fieldName) AND empty($value)) {
        $this->throwError(API_PARAM_REQUIRED, $fieldName . " value is required");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `empty()` function you check for the value

```
$str = '';
// or 
$str = null;
// or 
$str = false;
var_dump(empty($str)) // output => true
```

To check if a variable is defined you can use `isset`

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.isset.php

Answer (score 3):

testing your variable should be done by using the identity operator.

```
if (!$var){}
```

or

```
if  ($var === null){} //checks by type
```

or

```
if (empty($field)){}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're main problem is that you're passing the value (grabbed from the array) to the method and checking that. Because at that point, if the array key is not set, a warning is triggered and the value is coerced to `null`.

`empty()`: Will return true when the variable is not set OR if it evaluates to some falsey value (e.g. `false`, `null`, `[]`, `""`, etc)

`isset()`: Will return true ONLY if the value is not set.

So:

```
$a = ['one' => false];
empty($a['one']); //true
isset($a['one']); //true
isset($a['two']); //false
```

So you could edit you validation function like so:

```
public function validateParameter($fieldName, &$inputArray, $required = true){

    if($required){
        if(!isset($inputArray[$fieldName])){
            $this->throwError(EMPTY_PARAMETER, $fieldName . " parameter is missing");
        } else if (empty($inputArray[$fieldName])){
            $this->throwError(API_PARAM_REQUIRED, $fieldName . " value is required");
        }
    } else {
        if(!isset($inputArray[$fieldName])){
            return null;
        }
    }

    return $inputArray[$fieldName];
  }
```

Note: since you are checking a class attribute `$this->param`. You may avoid passing the array to the method and just reference `$this->param` in the function, unless it should be more reusable.

I didn't completely understand you desired result in the missing block, but made a reasonable assumption